# _udf_code error when using filter within a Python Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Been trying to get started with using Python procedures in Snowflake. I have another basic procedure that works fine, but I can't get this part working. I am hoping to filter a dataframe, but getting this weird error.

```
[P0000][100357] Python Interpreter Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "_udf_code.py", line 6, in run File "/usr/lib/python_udf/de--0d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/telemetry.py", line 133, in wrap result = func(*args, **kwar ...
```

Here is the stored procedure, its fairly simple

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utility.procedure.RECREATE_STALE_STREAM_PYTHON()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
  HANDLER = 'run'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
def run(session):
    show_streams = "show streams in account;"
    streams = session.sql(show_streams)
    stale_streams = streams.filter(col('stale') == 'true').collect();
    return stale_streams
$$;
```

Thanks in advance

I have tried everything I can think of, nothing seems to work

Comment: The full stack trace is not visible, so I tried to run it for myself. In my case it fails with the error: `invalid identifier 'STALE'
 in function RECREATE_STALE_STREAM_PYTHON with handler run`. If you see the same, try this: `(col('"stale"') == 'true')` Double quotes will help to save the small letters that will match the column name returned by the `show streams`

Comment: This works perfectly.  I didn't know how to find the full stack trace, have now found that thru the console, so that should help a lot!  Next step is to get better at reading through it to find the actual error.

Thanks for the response!  This fixed the issue, I had a feeling I was looking in the wrong direction, but couldn't find anything to help narrow it down.

But I can't mark your comment as the answer

Comment: I am glad it worked. I posted it as an answer, with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored procedure called from Python code fails with the error:

> invalid identifier 'STALE'

In this case it happens because Python generated the actual SQL statement using the column name without double-quotes while the actual column name is written in small letters.

If there are no double-quotes in a SQL command the object names are always capitalized. (which is fine in 99% of the cases).

However, if the object identifier is written not in all capitals, then the double-quotes must be used to preserve the case. In Python it would look as adding a pair of double quotes around the object identifier:

```
(col('"stale"') == 'true')
```

More details about quoted and unquoted identifiers can be found in the doc: [Identifier Requirements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html)

You are right that the full stack trace of the error can be found in the UI console. Also, you can find the actual query that was generated by Python (History in Classic UI, or Activity in Snowsight) and check it correctness, e.g. by running outside of the stored procedure call and debug using the SQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your UDF definition signature:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utility.procedure.RECREATE_STALE_STREAM_PYTHON()
```

Does not match the signature of the Pyhon function specified as the handler:

```
def run(session):
```

The UDF definition has zero parameters in the signature. The handler has one parameter in its signature. They need to match in number and type (loose typing in Python is okay, but must be able to be cast).

There's an example Python UDF that shows the matching UDF definition signature and handler signature here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-creating.html#specifying-multiple-import-files

The UDF signature:

```
create or replace function multiple_import_files(s string)
```

Matches the handler's signature:

```
def compute(s):
```

One option would be to pass in the value for `session` in the UDF signature. However, be careful of the name since session is s reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the response on this, I added the session to the main function of the procedure because of this error originally.  This seems to be one way that Python Procedures differ from Python Functions, maybe.  Unless there is some other way I should be passing the session into the main function?

Python function is defined with 0 arguments (including session), but stored procedure definition contains 0 arguments. Python function arguments are expected to be session and stored procedure defined arguments in function RECREATE_STALE_STREAM_PYTHON with handler run